# Make the MVCContrib-generated-column-names to make ajax calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

It sounds like a simple question, but I've been strugling with it this entire afternoon. I'm trying to put a grid in a PartialView with pagination, sorting and everything. My first problem was the pager links: they did not hold my filter options, since it was not on the pages query string. That's how I solved it:

```
public class PaginationContainer
{
    public IPagination PaginatedResult { get; set; }
    public RouteValueDictionary RouteValueDictionary { get; set; } 
}
```

I created this class, which is then used by my pager:

```
@using MvcContrib.UI.Pager
@model AqxWeb.Models.PaginationContainer
@{
    string action = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();
    string controller = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue.ToString();
}
@functions
{
    public RouteValueDictionary GetRoute(int page)
    {
        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();

        foreach (string key in Model.RouteValueDictionary.Keys)
        {
            routeValues[key] = Model.RouteValueDictionary[key];
        }
        routeValues["page"] = page;



        return routeValues;
    }   
}
<p />
<div class='pagination'>
    <span class='paginationLeft'>Mostrando @Model.PaginatedResult.FirstItem - @Model.PaginatedResult.LastItem
        de @Model.PaginatedResult.TotalItems</span> <span class='paginationRight'>
            @{
                if (Model.PaginatedResult.HasPreviousPage)
                {<text> @Html.ActionLink("Primeira", action, controller, GetRoute(1), new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "paging" } })
                | </text>}
                else
                {<text> Primeira | </text>}
                if (Model.PaginatedResult.HasPreviousPage)
                {<text>@Html.ActionLink("Anterior", action, controller, GetRoute(Model.PaginatedResult.PageNumber - 1), new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "paging" } })
                | </text>}
                else
                {<text>Anterior | </text>}
                if (Model.PaginatedResult.HasNextPage)
                {<text>@Html.ActionLink("Próxima", action, controller, GetRoute(Model.PaginatedResult.PageNumber + 1), new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "paging" } })
                | </text>}
                else
                {<text>Próxima | </text>}
                if (Model.PaginatedResult.HasNextPage)
                {<text>@Html.ActionLink("Última", action, controller, GetRoute(Model.PaginatedResult.TotalPages), new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "paging" } })</text>}
                else
                {<text>Última</text>}                                             
            }
        </span>
</div>
```

All I have to do is to fill this dictionary, something I do on the ActionMethod.

Now I need a similar solution for sorting ... I need to override the table headers created by MVCContrib to add this filter options and to add a class attribute called "paging", which is what I use to make the ajax calls. The only exposed method that could help is `.Header(string)` for `IGridColumn<>`, and, honestly, it sucks (I'll have to do so much stuff by hand in order to achieve my goal). So I was trying to create an extension method to cope with this, which proved quite difficult, since the `.Header(string)` is not exposed:

(Please overlook the bad naming)

```
public static IGridColumn<T> Ajaxify(this IGridColumn<T> column, string columnName, string className, RouteValueDictionary routeValueDictionary)
{
    string newDecoration = "<td> <a href="+GetRoute(routeValueDictionary)+"class=\""+className+"\">"+ columnName + "</a></td>";
     return column.Header(newDecoration);
}
```

I think my intention here is quite clean, but this method wouldn't work, because somehow I can't access the `.Header(string)` method. Any ideas?